# Various errors while parsing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

Attempting to parse json from a url requiring login. Including all my code here as I'm not sure where the error is.

```
try: import simplejson as json
except ImportError: import json
import urllib2

username = 'user'
password = '1234'
url = "https://www.blah.com/someplace"

# set up the username/password/url request
password_mgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, "https://www.blah.com", username, password)
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = opener.open(request)

# option 1
json_object = json.loads(str(response))

#option 2
json_object = json.loads(response)
```

If I run the code with option 1 (commenting out option 2), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsontest.py", line 22, in <module>
    json_object = json.loads(str(request))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 413, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 420, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("No JSON object could be decoded", s, idx)
simplejson.decoder.JSONDecodeError: No JSON object could be decoded: line 1 column 0 (char 0)
```

If I run option 2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jsontest.py", line 23, in <module>
    json_object = json.loads(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 413, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 402, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

My sample JSON is valid as far as I can tell:

> {"set1":[{"data1":"411","data2":"2033","data3":"1","data4":"43968077","data5":"217","data6":"106828","data7":[]}],
>     "set2":{"data8":"411","data9":"2033","data10":"43968077","data11":"217223360","data12":"106828"}}

simplejson version = 2.3.2,
Python 2.7.3

Very new to all this so any pointers would be very helpful.

Comment: why are you trying to read the request object?  Don't you want the response?  response = opener.open(req);data = response.read()

Comment: Don't you mean `json_object = json.loads(response)`?  (not `request`?)  Just a typo?

Comment: Ugh. Yes I meant response. Edited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to decode the *response*, not the request:

```
json_object = json.load(response)
```

The response is a file-like object, so you can use `.load()` to have the json library read it directly.

Alternatively (at the cost of some temporary memory use), use the `.loads()` function with the fully read response:

```
json_object = json.loads(response.read())
```

Note that python 2.7 already includes the simplejson library, renamed to [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
import json
```

Comment: Correct, I needed to use .read() or load(). The 'response' was a typo yes. I now have a ready-to-go py dict, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use response, not request (maybe just a typo?), but furthermore you need to use `response.read()` to get the body of the HTTP response:

```
json_object = json.loads(response.read())
```