# Converting string file into json format file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok , let say that I have a string text file named "string.txt" , and I want to convert it into a json text file.
What I suppose to do? I have tried to use 'json.loads()' ,but it never works with me!
here is a part from my text file :

```
rdian","id":"161428670566653"},{"category":"Retail and consumer merchandise","category_list":[{"id":"187937741228885","name":"Electronics Store"},{"id":"191969860827280","name":"Photographic Services & Equipment"}
```

any help please?
edit:
I have use this code:

```
import json

f = open("string.txt", 'w')
f1 = open("stringJson.txt", 'r')


f.write(json.dumps(json.loads(f), indent=1))


f.close()
```

the  error is like this:

obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

[image]

Comment: That certainly looks like a fragment of JSON. What's the error you get when you try to load it?

Comment: For one, you have two double-quotes before string.txt => `f = open(""string.txt", 'w')`; Second, your JSON snippet (first code block) is truncated/missing some of it.

Comment: @Nicarus: yea it is just a typo when I copied my code here!

Comment: OK. How about the JSON? It looks like the first part of it is cut off.

Comment: @Nicarus: I know that becasue it is very large it just give you a snapshot of it !

Comment: OK - so you know for sure the text is valid JSON?

Comment: Googled your error - this was the first result. See if it helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326370/various-errors-while-parsing-json-in-python

Comment: no because it is not in json format !

Comment: it is like this line after line                                          {"data":[{"category":"University","category_list":[{"id":"108051929285833","name":"College &

Comment: @arzeramade Take it easy with the tone - just trying to better understand what you are asking.

Comment: Does the file contain line breaks? Post a few complete lines in that case.

Comment: @Nicarus I have included a snapshot of my file

Comment: That snapshot doesn't help because it could be anywhere in the file where it would be out of format for JSON and therefore not load properly or at all.

Comment: You may have multiple JSON objects in the file. In that case see [Retrieving JSON objects from a text file (using Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8730119/222914)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import json
with open("string.txt", "rb") as fin:
    content = json.load(fin)
with open("stringJson.txt", "wb") as fout:
    json.dump(content, fout, indent=1)
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage

Comment: Extra data: line 1 column 102663 - line 1 column 106497 (char 102662 - 106496) this is error

Comment: @arzeramade It seems pretty obvious from the errors that the text file  is not completely in the appropriate format to be loaded as JSON. You should review the file - fix the issue and retry Shaung's solution.

Comment: @arzeramade What is there in the indicated range? Use eg. this to check: `print open("string.txt","rb").read()[102662:106497]`

Comment: @Nicarus: this what I was telling you , do I have to do this manually?in order to be appropriate ti loaded as json?

Comment: @Nicarus: yea I know that but how to make a text to be valid for json loads?

Comment: @JanneKarila: it print large chunks of data exists on the "string.txt" file

Comment: i have use this to get the file                                        s= urllib2.urlopen("https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=5000&type=page&q=%26&access_token="+accesstoken+"&__after_id=139433456868").read()

Comment: and the I have store it like this :                                      f.write(s)
I have tried to store here as json but it never works

Comment: @arzeramade I don't know what to tell you. I think it was suggested to  check if it contained multiple JSON objects - try that.

Comment: @arzeramade Try another query that gives a small result. That would be much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how your `txt` file is structured. But suppose you have a structured `txt` file like the following:

```
BASE|30-06-2008|2007|2|projected
BASE|30-06-2007|2010|1|projected
BASE|30-06-2007|2009|3|projected
BASE|30-06-2007|2020|2|projected
...
```

You could use a script like this:

```py
import codecs
import json

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_filepath = "your_data.txt"

field_names = [
    "Scenario",
    "Date",
    "Year",
    "Quarter",
    "Value"
]

data_array = np.genfromtxt(raw_filepath, delimiter="|", dtype=None, encoding="utf-8")
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_array)
df.columns = field_names
result = df.to_json(orient="records")
parsed = json.loads(result)
out_json_path = "your_data.json"

### saves pandas dataframe in .json format
json.dump(
    parsed, codecs.open(out_json_path, "w", encoding="utf-8"), sort_keys=False, indent=4
)
```

**Explanation**

To load a dataset in Numpy, we can use the `genfromtxt()` function. We can specify data file name, delimiter (which is optional but often used), and number of rows to skip if we have a header row. The `genfromtxt()` function has a parameter called `dtype` for specifying data types of each column(this
parameter is optional). Without specifying the types, all types will be casted the same to the more general/precise type and numpy will try
infer the type of a column.

In this part `df.to_json(orient="records")` we are Encoding/decoding a Dataframe using 'records' formatted JSON. Note that index labels are not preserved with this encoding. This, way, we can have an output like this, as described in the  [Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
>>>result = df.to_json(orient="records")
>>>parsed = json.loads(result)
>>>json.dumps(parsed, indent=4)  
[
    {
        "col 1": "a",
        "col 2": "b"
    },
    {
        "col 1": "c",
        "col 2": "d"
    }
]
```