# log file to json file conversion

Tags: python, json

I have some log files.i want to convert content of these files to `json` format using python.required json format is

```
{
"content":  {
       "text" :      // raw text to be split
},
"metadata";:  {
       ...meta data fields, eg. hostname, logpath,
       other fields passed from client...
     }
}
```

i tried `json` dump in `python 2.7` but unexpected errors are coming..any suggestion will be great..
thanks..

error I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "LogToJson.py", line 12, 
in <module> f.write(json.dumps(json.loads(f1), indent=1)) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, 
in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) 
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, 
in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

sample data:

```
Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: 
<info> address 9.124.29.61 
Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: 
<info> prefix 24 (255.255.255.0) 
Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: 
<info> gateway 9.124.29.1
```

Comment: please add the errors you encounter

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LogToJson.py", line 12, in <module>
    f.write(json.dumps(json.loads(f1), indent=1))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: Already tried that answer from a post ..it is showing ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: could you provide sample data?

Comment: Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: <info>   address 9.124.29.61
Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]: <info>   gateway 9.124.29.1

Comment: simple syslog files..you can see even in your laptop syslog files under /home/var/log folder

Comment: It might be better to update your question to include your code, sample input and error messages instead of posting additional comments.

Comment: i used code of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20901018/converting-string-file-into-json-format-file  ..can u give me some suggestion ..how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code you have written to accomplish your task, it is hard to recommend something. But, from your comments I suppose that you are using `json.loads()` to read from file, but it works with the python strings in json format only. To read from a file you should use `json.load()`, but in this case, the contents of the file must be already in json format. So, I suggest to read log file line by line, make some parsing, give it some structure (e.g. create a python dict object with it), and then convert it to json and write it back to new file.
You better check [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a parser which can convert your syslog output into a json format. I suggest using re to parse it and use the values in your dict as required.

Example Code:

```
import re

output = {'content': {}, 'metadata': {} }

parsed_data = re.findall(r'(\w{3} \d+ [\d+:]+) (\S+) (\S+):', 'Jan 27 10:46:57 sabya-ThinkPad-T420 NetworkManager[1462]:')

output['metadata']['time'] = parsed_data[0][0]
output['metadata']['host'] = parsed_data[0][1]
output['metadata']['info'] = parsed_data[0][2]

json.dumps(output)
```